# v8 setting Handle<Value> array howto?

Tags: c++, window, v8

I want to set a `Handle<Value>` of an array. I'm a beginner to v8 and i can't found how to set it 
when I do for example:

```
Persistent<Context> fcontext
Handle<Value> Arr = Array::New(0);
Persistent<Function> Func;
Handle<Value> result = Func->Call(fcontext->Global(), 0, Arr);
```

I receive this error:

```
 error C2664: 'v8::Function::Call' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'v8::Handle<T>' to 'v8::Handle<T> []'
    1>        with
    1>        [
    1>            T=v8::Value
    1>        ]
```

How do I make a `Handle<Value>` of an array with 1 element ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const unsigned argc = 1;
Local<Value> argv[argc] = { Local<Value>::New(String::New("Hello World!")) };
func->Call(Context::GetCurrent()->Global(), argc, argv);
```

More examples:

- http://izs.me/v8-docs/examples.html
- http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html